# xml data into php or js

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I am editing a web page and came across an xml problem. Currently the website uses an xml file with some information, which is sent to a flash app that displays that info in a scrolling headline. So the xml consists of a `<newsTicker>` tag, and multiple items inside the tag:

```
<item>
<header>
FEATURED ARTIST
</header>
<date/>
<body>
Some Artist
</body>
<link>
www.somelink.com
</link>
<graphic>
AnImage.gif
</graphic>
</item>
```

What I am supposed to do is write a javascript code that will get this info, and display it in the same way. The only problem is that I do not know how to parse each item from the xml into the javascript since I never worked with xml. I would even be more comfortable with getting the data into php and then rendering the js, but its not a big difference - however you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: what have u tried? can you show some code which you have tried?
is the xml data is returning from AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Parse to an XML DOM object then you can access it with js

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "xml text here";
var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/xml").documentElement;
```

Then you can get all the info you want with querySelector and querySelectorAll methods.

example:

```
var items = node.querySelectorAll("item"); //get all items

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   var item = items[i];
   var header = item.querySelector("header"); //get the header of the current item
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nemo13/yRwkW/